# An equation system in the integers

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am trying to solve the following equation system for an integer $k$: 
$$\begin{align*}
k \alpha &\equiv 0\pmod{n}\\ 
\beta \frac{r^{k \alpha} - 1}{r^\alpha - 1} &\equiv 0 \pmod{m}
\end{align*}$$
where $r^n \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$.

I could also use some bounds on $k$. This system arises when I try to determine the order of elements in a semidirect product of cyclic groups $\mathbb{Z}_n \ltimes_r \mathbb{Z}_n$. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: $\alpha,\beta,n,m,r$ are all given?

Comment: Yes, they are all given, and $k$ is the indeterminate.